# Expected number of games in the Baseball World Series

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider the following problem, from *Understanding Probability* by Henk Tijms.

> In the World Series Baseball, the final two teams play a series
>   consisting of a possible seven games until such time that one of the
>   two teams has won four games. In one such final, two unevenly matched
>   teams are pitted against each other and the probability that the
>   weaker team will win any given game is equal to $p=0.45$. Assuming that
>   the results of the various games are independent from each other,
>   calculate the probability of the weaker team winning the final. What
>   are the expected value and the standard deviation of the number of
>   games the final will take?

The probability of the weaker team winning is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^3 \binom{7}{k} (1-p)^kp^{7-k}\simeq 0.3917.
$$
For the expected value of the number of games, I consider the following table, where I list the number of possible wins for each of the two teams:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{strong team} & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\text{weak team} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
\end{array}
$$
which leads me to the expression:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^3 (4+k)\binom{4+k}{k}p^k(1-p)^4 + \sum_{k=0}^3 (4+k)\binom{4+k}{k}p^4(1-p)^k \simeq 8.622
$$
the result, however, is wrong. The only thing that I can think of is that I am counting in a wrong way the number of games with a given number of wins for the two teams.

I have found the solution of this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701135/what-are-the-expected-value-and-the-standard-deviation-of-the-number-of-games-th), but why is my approach wrong?

Comment: @vadim123, the OP probably meant to sum from $k=0$ to $3$, not $7$.

Comment: @barry-cipra, indeed, I will fix it immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you count all possibilities that the series finishes, e.g., 4-2 in favor of the stronger team, you count every time the stronger team wins 4 games and the weaker team wins 2, in any order, as a 6-game series. However, if the stronger team wins games 1,3,4,5, and the weaker team wins games 2,6, the series lasted only 5 games (and game 6 was never played). So not every arrangement of 4 strongenr-team-wins and 2 weaker-team-wins gives a legitimate 6-game series.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is almost right with the choose formula on both terms to be ${(4+k-1)\choose k}$ the reason being, the last one of p or (1-p) is fixed and that the the k games of the loser on both terms should find their way within (total number of games - 1) slots with the last being fixed.  Other than that your logic is right and is no different than the solution that you referred to.

Answer (score 2):

@BallBoy's answer explains why your calculation is incorrect. To fix this, note that you should only count combinations where the $k$ games won by the losing team do not include the last game (the losing team can't win the last game). So that gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^3(4+k)\binom{3+k}kp^k(1-p)^4+\sum_{k=0}^3(4+k)\binom{3+k}kp^4(1-p)^k\approx 5.78$$